# Issues with fork() loop, execlp() and wait()

Tags: while-loop, fork, exec, wait

I have a problem with this piece of code. The loop should read file names from a list.txt file, then fork at most n times (terminal defined) and sort files containing ints. problem is, father process never waits for children termination. Am I missing something?

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s", fname) != EOF){
    if(i<n){
        if(!fork()){
            i++;
            execlp("sort", "sort", "-n", "-o", fname, fname, NULL);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } 
    } else {
        printf("WAIT FOR FORK TERMINATION\n");
        wait(&status);
        i--;
    }
}
```

I don't know if the problem is related to execlp executing the sort command faster than it takes the father to reach wait condition or what